# WebDriver opens Chrome with data:, stuck on address bar (Python Selenium)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Trying to open YouTube (or any other website) using Selenium in Python. When I run the program, a blank browser window pops up, with phrase `data:,` in the address bar, and it stays right there until timeout. What should I do to open a web page correctly?

---

Additional information:

- Chrome: Version 80.0.3987.87 (64-bit)
- [ChromeDriver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads): Version 80.0.3987.16 (latest, said to be compatible with version of my Chrome)
- I did not place `chromedriver.exe` in the same directory with Chrome.
- Operating System: Windows 10

---

Sample Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r"C:\explicit\path\to\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com")
```

Screenshot:
[blank window with data;, on address bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcQFT.jpg)

Comment: Apparently, the problem is solved after restarting the laptop ... Initially, the pop-up window will stuck at `data;,` for ages until it terminates, now it's all good.

Answer (score 0):

I've been (and still have) struggling a lot with this. Some runtime errors may leave Chromium processes alive.
After a little research I found that new Chromium instances sometimes hang if another Chromium process is present in the system.
Just find and kill that process, then run your script again.
Anyway, I still don't know why can't we use two Chromium instances at the same time, it's kind of a limitation for running tests in parallel.

In Linux I use something like this: `sudo kill -9 $(ps aux | grep chromium | awk '{print $2}')`

Comment: I found that the problem occurs when you start different Chrome driver processes with the same debugging port. The following code works : 
import socket \n sock=socket.socket() \n sock.bind(("",0)) \n port = sock.getsockname()[1] \n options.add_argument(f"--remote-debugging-port={port}")